# Monacaアプリ開発によるマルチデバイス間の画面サイズ統一ができない

Tags: monaca

Monacaを使用して、Android及びiOS向けのハイブリッドアプリを制作しております。

公式のマニュアルがかなり古いまま更新されていないようで、どうやら現在のMonacaでは、
マルチデバイス間で画面サイズ統一を図るために用意されていた monaca.viewport(640); が、
デフォルトでは利用できないようです。

そこで、｢JS/CSSコンポーネントの追加｣から別途、monaca-viewport-js を追加、
monaca.viewport(640); をスクリプト冒頭に記述して試してみたのですが、
Monaca IDEのプレビュー上では、画面サイズが統一できないどころか、
そこで処理が停止してしまうようです。

目的が達成できれば他の手段でも全く構いませんので、
Monacaでマルチデバイス間で画面サイズ統一を行う方法をご存知でしたら、
どなたかご教授のほどお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

自己解決いたしました。
大変稚拙なレベルな問題ではありますが、
もしかしたら今後同じように困る方もいるかもしれませんので、
参考までに、以下のとおり解決策を補足しておきます。

monaca.viewport();の記述方法が、公式マニュアルや
その他サイト等に記載されていた当時のものから変更があったようで、
monaca.viewport({width:640});とすることで、正常動作いたしました。

ですので手順としては、
１．｢JS/CSSコンポーネントの追加｣から monaca-viewport-js を追加
２．スクリプトに monaca.viewport({width:任意の仮想ビューポートサイズ}); を記述
となります。